# SVG not displaying in any browser

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to get an SVG to display in a HTML webpage, but I must be missing something.

I have a svg file called logo-a.svg this is the code for it:

```
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="197px" height="71px" viewbox="0 0 346 51">
<style type="text/css">
  .Arched_x0020_Green{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:0.25;stroke-miterlimit:1;}
  .st0{fill:#008751;}
  .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
  .st2{fill:#F9FBFB;}
</style>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-32.7222" y1="228.6171" x2="-32.0151" y2="227.9099">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#20AC4B"/>
  <stop  offset="0.9831" style="stop-color:#19361A"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect y="-0.1" class="st0" width="315.63" height="59.33"/>
<g>
  <path class="st1" d="M289.44,54.22c-1.58,1.58-4.15,1.58-5.73,0l-22.21-22.21c-1.58-1.58-1.58-4.15,0-5.73L283.7,4.06
    c1.58-1.58,4.15-1.58,5.73,0l22.21,22.21c1.58,1.58,1.58,4.15,0,5.73L289.44,54.22z"/>
  <path class="st1" d="M68.19,30.39c0-8.81,5.82-20.2,21.28-20.2c12.83,0,20.82,7.47,20.82,19.27c0,11.8-8.24,21.12-21.33,21.12
    C74.17,50.59,68.19,39.51,68.19,30.39z M103.08,31.37c0-11.54-6.65-18.7-15.1-18.7c-5.93,0-12.68,3.3-12.68,16.13
    c0,10.72,5.92,19.22,15.82,19.22C94.73,48.01,103.08,46.26,103.08,31.37z"/>
  <path class="st2" d="M13.81,36.42c-0.26,0-0.36,0.1-0.46,0.41l-2.78,7.37c-0.52,1.29-0.77,2.53-0.77,3.14c0,0.93,0.46,1.6,2.06,1.6
    h0.77c0.62,0,0.77,0.1,0.77,0.41c0,0.41-0.31,0.51-0.87,0.51c-1.65,0-3.86-0.15-5.46-0.15c-0.57,0-3.4,0.15-6.08,0.15
    C0.31,49.87,0,49.76,0,49.35c0-0.31,0.21-0.41,0.62-0.41c0.47,0,1.18-0.05,1.6-0.1c2.37-0.31,3.35-2.06,4.38-4.64l12.93-32.36
    c0.62-1.49,0.93-2.06,1.44-2.06c0.46,0,0.77,0.46,1.29,1.65c1.24,2.83,9.48,23.86,12.78,31.69c1.96,4.64,3.45,5.36,4.53,5.62
    c0.77,0.15,1.55,0.21,2.16,0.21c0.41,0,0.67,0.05,0.67,0.41c0,0.41-0.46,0.51-2.37,0.51c-1.86,0-5.62,0-9.74-0.11
    c-0.93-0.05-1.55-0.05-1.55-0.41c0-0.31,0.21-0.41,0.72-0.47c0.36-0.1,0.72-0.56,0.46-1.18l-4.12-10.92
    c-0.1-0.26-0.26-0.36-0.52-0.36H13.81z M24.32,33.84c0.26,0,0.31-0.16,0.26-0.31L19.94,20.8c-0.05-0.21-0.1-0.46-0.26-0.46
    c-0.15,0-0.26,0.26-0.31,0.46l-4.74,12.68c-0.05,0.21,0,0.36,0.21,0.36H24.32z"/>
  <path class="st1" d="M29.14,49.76c-0.9-0.07,3.01-0.17,3.01-1.3c0-2.83-2.31-9.34-2.26-10.16c0.05-0.77,0.2-1.34,0.62-1.34
    c0.46,0,0.52,0.46,0.52,0.88c0,0.67,0.22-0.97,0.55-0.11c3.6,9.41,13.99,10.96,19.98,10.39c4.62-0.44,6.9-3.14,6.9-5.87
    c0-2.52-0.77-4.89-5.05-8.24l-2.37-1.86c-5.67-4.43-7.63-8.04-7.63-12.21c0-5.67,4.74-9.74,11.9-9.74c3.35,0,5.51,0.52,6.85,0.88
    c0.46,0.1,0.72,0.26,0.72,0.62c0,0.67-0.21,2.17-0.21,6.19c0,1.13-0.15,1.55-0.57,1.55c-0.36,0-0.51-0.31-0.51-0.93
    c0-0.47-0.26-2.06-1.34-3.4c-0.77-0.98-2.27-2.53-5.62-2.53c-3.81,0-6.13,2.22-6.13,5.31c0,2.37,1.19,4.17,5.46,7.42l1.44,1.08
    c6.23,4.69,8.45,8.25,8.45,13.14c0,2.99-1.13,6.54-4.84,8.96c-2.58,1.65-5.46,2.11-8.19,2.11C47.84,50.59,31.33,49.94,29.14,49.76z
    "/>
  <path class="st1" d="M115.85,25.85c0-7.83,0-9.27-0.1-10.92c-0.11-1.75-0.52-2.58-2.22-2.94c-0.41-0.1-1.29-0.15-2.01-0.15
    c-0.57,0-0.88-0.1-0.88-0.46c0-0.36,0.36-0.46,1.13-0.46c2.73,0,5.98,0.15,7.06,0.15c1.75,0,5.67-0.15,7.26-0.15
    c3.25,0,6.7,0.31,9.48,2.22c1.45,0.98,3.51,3.61,3.51,7.06c0,3.81-1.6,7.32-6.8,11.54c4.58,5.77,8.14,10.35,11.18,13.55
    c2.89,2.99,5,3.35,5.77,3.5c0.57,0.1,1.03,0.16,1.44,0.16c0.41,0,0.62,0.16,0.62,0.41c0,0.41-0.36,0.51-0.98,0.51h-4.89
    c-2.89,0-4.18-0.26-5.51-0.98c-2.22-1.18-4.17-3.61-7.06-7.57c-2.06-2.84-4.43-6.34-5.1-7.11c-0.26-0.31-0.57-0.36-0.93-0.36
    l-4.48-0.1c-0.26,0-0.41,0.1-0.41,0.41v0.72c0,4.79,0,8.87,0.26,11.03c0.15,1.49,0.46,2.63,2.01,2.84c0.77,0.1,1.9,0.21,2.52,0.21
    c0.41,0,0.62,0.16,0.62,0.41c0,0.36-0.36,0.51-1.03,0.51c-2.99,0-6.8-0.15-7.57-0.15c-0.98,0-4.23,0.15-6.29,0.15
    c-0.67,0-1.03-0.15-1.03-0.51c0-0.26,0.2-0.41,0.82-0.41c0.77,0,1.39-0.1,1.86-0.21c1.03-0.21,1.29-1.34,1.49-2.84
    c0.26-2.16,0.26-6.23,0.26-10.97V25.85z M121.93,29.93c0,0.57,0.1,0.77,0.46,0.93c1.08,0.36,2.63,0.52,3.92,0.52
    c2.06,0,2.73-0.21,3.66-0.88c1.54-1.14,3.04-3.5,3.04-7.73c0-7.32-4.85-9.43-7.88-9.43c-1.29,0-2.21,0.05-2.73,0.21
    c-0.36,0.1-0.46,0.31-0.46,0.72V29.93z"/>
  <path class="st1" d="M144.82,30.39c0-8.81,5.82-20.2,21.28-20.2c12.83,0,20.82,7.47,20.82,19.27c0,11.8-8.24,21.12-21.33,21.12
    C150.8,50.59,144.82,39.51,144.82,30.39z M179.7,31.37c0-11.54-6.65-18.7-15.1-18.7c-5.93,0-12.68,3.3-12.68,16.13
    c0,10.72,5.93,19.22,15.82,19.22C171.36,48.01,179.7,46.26,179.7,31.37z"/>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M272.7,48.93c-0.63,0-1.65-0.15-3.21-0.77c-2.79-1.09-5.12-3.41-7.39-5.58
        c-2.01-1.91-10.67-11.2-12.56-13.67l-0.07-0.05c-0.62,0.81-1.84,2.3-3.55,4.14c2.16,2.71,9.62,11.53,11.74,13.4
        c2.22,1.97,3.62,3.1,6.41,3.36c1.09,0.11,2.02,0.11,3.56,0.11h4.51c0.98,0,1.24-0.15,1.24-0.52
        C273.37,49.04,273.07,48.93,272.7,48.93z"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st1" d="M243.64,30.23h-0.26v2.55c0.42-0.44,0.83-0.87,1.2-1.28c-0.17-0.21-0.3-0.38-0.38-0.49L243.64,30.23z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M228.24,43.22c-2.75,1.51-7.52,4.34-14.47,4.37c-6.9,0.03-16.23-6.08-16.23-18.34c0-5,0.98-9.89,4.74-13.34
      c2.27-2.06,5.21-3.19,9.69-3.19c4.74,0,8.76,1.39,10.46,3.19c1.29,1.34,1.96,3.14,2.01,4.74c0,0.72,0.1,1.13,0.52,1.13
      c0.46,0,0.56-0.41,0.62-1.19c0.11-1.03,0.05-3.86,0.16-5.57c0.1-1.8,0.26-2.42,0.26-2.83c0-0.31-0.2-0.57-0.77-0.62
      c-1.54-0.15-3.19-0.62-5.15-0.88c-2.37-0.31-4.28-0.52-7.47-0.52c-7.68,0-12.57,2.06-16.28,5.46c-4.95,4.54-6.03,10.62-6.03,14.12
      c0,5,1.34,10.77,6.39,15.2c4.69,4.07,10.63,6.08,17.67,5.62c7.93-0.52,16.29-6.13,22.77-11.78c0-0.77,0.01-1.57,0.01-2.39
      C234.24,39.16,231.24,41.58,228.24,43.22z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M243.17,26.32h-0.24v-2.18c0-7.52,0-7.79,0.1-9.37c0.1-1.73,0.5-2.57,1.83-2.82c0.59-0.1,0.89-0.15,1.38-0.15
      c0.4,0,0.69-0.1,0.69-0.45c0-0.34-0.35-0.44-1.04-0.44c-1.68,0-4.8,0.15-5.98,0.15c-1.19,0-4.3-0.15-6.92-0.15
      c-0.74,0-1.09,0.1-1.09,0.44c0,0.35,0.29,0.45,0.84,0.45c0.69,0,1.54,0.05,1.93,0.15c1.63,0.35,2.03,1.14,2.13,2.82
      c0.1,1.58,0.1,1.86,0.1,9.37v8.71c0,0.49,0,0.41,0,0.88C241.55,29.25,244.09,25.32,243.17,26.32z"/>
    <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M237.47,41.41c-0.02,2.93-0.07,3.12-0.25,4.62c-0.2,1.44-0.45,2.54-1.44,2.74c-0.45,0.1-1.05,0.2-1.79,0.2
        c-0.6,0-0.8,0.15-0.8,0.4c0,0.35,0.35,0.5,1,0.5c1.99,0,5.13-0.15,6.28-0.15c1.24,0,4.38,0.15,7.18,0.15
        c0.54,0,0.95-0.15,0.95-0.5c0-0.25-0.25-0.4-0.65-0.4c-0.65,0-1.74-0.1-2.44-0.2c-1.25-0.2-1.7-1.3-1.8-2.69
        c-0.15-2.14-0.15-6.08-0.15-10.67v0.17C241.85,37.37,239.79,39.39,237.47,41.41z"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st1" d="M254.09,17.15c-0.85,0.95-2.52,2.7-4.3,4.56c-3.38,4.44-7.83,10.05-12.68,14.71c0,0.82,0,1.62-0.01,2.39
      c2.4-2.09,4.53-4.18,6.29-6.03v-2.55h0.26l0.57,0.77c0.08,0.11,0.21,0.28,0.38,0.49c2.42-2.63,3.89-4.53,3.98-4.77
      C248.78,26.17,252.11,20.62,254.09,17.15z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M248.18,27.4c1.76-1.85,9.54-9.58,11.13-11.13c2.22-2.16,3.97-3.25,5.57-3.86c0.98-0.36,2.27-0.57,2.99-0.57
      c0.51,0,0.77-0.1,0.77-0.46c0-0.36-0.36-0.46-0.88-0.46c-1.6,0-4.43,0.15-6.03,0.15c-1.39,0-4.23-0.15-5.31-0.15
      c-0.57,0-0.82,0.1-0.82,0.46c0,0.31,0.2,0.41,0.67,0.52c0.52,0.1,0.72,0.46,0.72,1.03c0,0.88-1.13,2.16-2.58,3.86
      c-0.09,0.1-0.2,0.23-0.33,0.37c-1.98,3.47-5.3,9.02-5.51,9.57c-0.02,0.07-0.18,0.3-0.45,0.65l0.07,0.05
      C248.19,27.41,248.19,27.4,248.18,27.4z"/>
  </g>
  <path class="st0" d="M269.57,31.17c1.44,0.11,2.81,0.4,4.23,0.51c4.83,0.36,9.84,0,14.55,0c2.54,0,5.04,0,7.45,0
    c2.23,0,4.75,0.48,6.6-0.85c0-0.34,0-0.68,0-1.02c-3.06-4.04-13.16-4.06-21.15-4.06c-1.2,0-2.55-0.05-3.72,0
    c-1.24,0.06-2.63-0.03-3.39,0.17c-0.81,0.21-1.85,1.85-2.71,2.2c-2.24,0.93-6.39,0.38-9.47,0.51c-1.13,0.05-2.29,0.07-3.44,0.08
    c0.46,0.57,1.16,1.37,1.98,2.3C263.55,30.9,266.61,30.95,269.57,31.17z"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M270.82,20.5c2.94,0,6.47-0.57,8.8,0.17c1.15,0.36,1.73,1.51,2.88,2.03c1.11,0.5,2.65,0.79,4.23,0.85
    c4.78,0.16,9.63-0.8,14.21-1.18c-4.03-0.6-9.61,0.37-13.37-0.51c0.6-0.93,1.98-0.61,3.04-0.67c3.1-0.19,7.23-0.16,10.32-0.51
    c-1.19-0.67-3.06-0.26-4.91-0.34c-2.87-0.12-6.06,0-8.46-0.51c0.27-0.66,1.13-0.61,1.69-0.68c3.4-0.39,8.29,0.41,11.68-0.17
    c-0.84-0.52-2.14-0.46-3.39-0.51c-2.24-0.08-5.09,0.03-7.61-0.17c-0.77-0.06-2.02-0.01-2.37-0.85c4.04-0.67,8.73,0.08,13.37-0.17
    c-0.3-0.57-1.15-0.43-1.69-0.51c-1.69-0.24-3.6-0.35-5.58-0.51c-3.73-0.29-7.91-0.85-10.83,0.34c-1.17,0.48-2.44,1.93-3.56,2.2
    c-1.15,0.28-2.97,0.15-4.4,0.17c-2.41,0.04-4.69,0.03-6.92-0.02c-0.48,0.48-1.03,1.02-1.6,1.59
    C267.84,20.52,269.33,20.5,270.82,20.5z"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M296.33,35.11c-3.52-1.94-9.5-2.63-13.03-0.34c-1.33,0.86-2.26,2.74-3.73,3.22c-1.09,0.36-2.88,0.28-4.4,0.34
    c-2.6,0.11-5.37,0.02-8.03-0.14c0.6,0.63,1.13,1.16,1.52,1.55c2.27-0.03,4.56,0,6.86,0.11c1.65,0.08,3.05-0.12,4.23,0.34
    c1.52,0.59,2.35,2.55,3.89,3.38c3.54,1.91,9.29,1.21,12.69-0.67c1.71-0.95,3.38-2.1,3.38-3.89
    C299.71,36.92,297.62,35.82,296.33,35.11z"/>
</g>
                      </svg>
```

Then I have a page in my website trying to display it like this:

```
<div class="brand-logo">
<object id="svg1" data="/images/logo-a.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? The SVG was created in illustrator, not sure if that makes any difference though.

Comment: 1. Set a namespace in the `<svg>` tag: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. 2. in the same tag, it must be `viewBox`, not `viewbox`.

Comment: More detail on the SVG head https://medium.com/@pnowelldesign/stuff-at-the-top-of-an-svg-f3ad198eb54e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your svg is not real svg, just an xml file while you don't declare its namespace

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="197px" height="71px" viewbox="0 0 346 51"   
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
```